# Why must metric tensor be invertible?

Tags: tensors

The metric can be written as a matrix, but why must this matrix be invertible? At the points where the matrix is singular, why is the metric not defined?

Comment: The matrix for a metric represents a bilinear form on the tangent space (in a certain basis).  You want this form to be symmetric, positive definite (usually), and non-degenerate.  This last condition ensures that no vector pairs to give zero with every other vector.  It is equivalent to the matrix being nonsingular.

Comment: @SammyBlack Well, in orthogonal coordinates every vector with every other vector gives zero.

Comment: @Yola - not unit vectors with themselves.

Answer (score 2):

This worried me at one time as well. The way I thought about it was by working at a fixed point and using the Gram-Schmidt process for inner products on the coordinate basis $\partial_1,...,\partial_n$ to produce an orthonormal basis $e_1,...,e_n$. It's a standard and easy fact that the matrices that represent these bilinear forms are related by $I=A^tgA$, where $I$ is the identity matrix (since $\{e_i\}$ is orthonormal), $g$ is the metric $g_{ij}$ with respect to the $\{\partial_i\}$ basis, and $A$ is the change of basis matrix taking the basis of partials to the orthonormal basis. Taking the determinant of both sides of this equation, and using the fact that $\det(A)=\det(A^t)\neq 0$, we see that $\det(g)\neq 0$ so $g$ is invertible.

Answer (score -2):

Given a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(\mathcal M,g)$ and some local tangent space $\mathrm T_p\mathcal M$ with coordinates $x^1,\dots, x^n$ , the volume form is given by
$$\mathrm dV=\sqrt{|\det g|}~\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \mathrm dx^i$$

So
$$g~\text{not invertible}\implies \det g=0\implies \mathrm dV=0$$

Which would imply our manifold is trivial, i.e, a single point.

Comment: To the downvoter - why? If I have an error in my reasoning, please elucidate me.